# Mongoose method to return id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling to code a method in my mongoose model that returns only an id of a specific record.

This is my (simplified) schema:

```
var PersonaSchema   = new Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    personal_firstname: String,
    created_at: { type: Date },
    updated_at: { type: Date }
});
```

I would like to search for a record by email, than return the id if it exists. Currently I have this method setup as a static method, which does not work as suspected. It does not return the id, but the whole mongoose object.

```
PersonaSchema.statics = {
  getPersonaId: function getPersonaId(email, cb) {
    this.findOne({ email: email }).select("_id").exec(function(err, persona) {
        if(err) {
            throw err;  
        } else {
            if(persona){
                return persona._id;
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

EDIT: I was not quite clear in my question. What I want to do is get the persona id as a single value in my controller method.

Underneath I have a now working version, with a callback version. However, I would like it to be without a callback. So that I send an email to a static function, which returns the persona._id. How would I do that, without a callback?

```
var personaId = Persona.addPersonaId(personaData, function(err, persona, data) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: You're not using the `cb` function to return the value. Using return inside an async function doesn't work the way you're using it.

Answer (score 2):

use callback instead of return.

```
.exec(function(err, persona) {
    if(err) {
        return cb( err, persona );  
    }
    cb( null, {id: persona._id} );
});
```

Comment: Don't throw the error either and use the callback for that as well.

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed. Although, I now understand I was not completely transparent in my question. In stead, I want to get the persona._id in my router as a single value, without using a callback function there. I have edited my question.

Comment: You can return the _id as a single value, but you need a callback function to retrieve it because the database call is asynchronous

Answer (score 2):

You could have this in the model:

```
PersonaSchema.statics = {
    getPersonaId: function (email, cb) {
        this.findOne({ email: email }).select('_id').exec(cb);
    }
};
```

And this somewhere else:

```
PersonaSchema.model.getPersonaId('test@test.com', function (err, persona) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error, express example:
        return next(err);
    }

    // here you have
    console.log(persona._id);
});
```